# In Drupal 7 With Latest CKEditor, Media upload button not working

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media

If i do install [Wysiwyg](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) + [CKEditor 3.6.6.1 ( 2013.02.20)](http://ckeditor.com/release/CKEditor-3.6.6.1) + [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module in Drupal 7 then the upload functionality works on ckeditor. Here is my screenshot:
[image]
But, if i install [CKEditor Drupal 7 Module](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) + [Media Module](https://drupal.org/project/media) then the upload functionality do not working on ckeditor. Here is my screenshot:
[image]
So, how i can enable the Upload section in Media Module? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:
in order to use the upload plugin, the user has to either have the **Edit media** or the Administer media permission.

Answer (score 0):

There is a settings page for controlling media in wysiwyg that allows you to configure this.

It is at admin/config/media/browser

The setting in question is "Enabled browser plugins". Check the "Upload" box.

Comment: Drupal 6? i'm in d7..

Comment: That is in drupal 7.

Comment: Actually I only use media 7.x-2.x versions. Are you in media 7.x-1.x?

Comment: OK, i am not telling about wysiwyg configuration, because the latest version of CKeditor do not depended on drupal wysiwyg module, if i use Media module with the latest version of CKEditor then there is no upload option.: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2O7s.png any idea?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a permission called 'Add and upload new files' under 'File Entity' which might help people. This added the missing Upload tab to the generic (non-CKEditor) media browser for me…

(Note you don't need the plupload module just for this - that's a fancy widget, whereas changing the permission just adds a standard Drupal file upload field.)